# How to upgrade kernel in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel, apt

I want to use Docker on my Linux server for which I need to upgrade the kernel to 3.10 or higher. So following [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/598934/133190) I was trying `sudo apt-get install linux-generic-lts-trusty`, which results in:

> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of
>   linux-generic-lts-trusty:  linux-generic-lts-trusty depends on
>   linux-generic; however:   Package linux-generic is not configured yet.
>
> dpkg: error processing package linux-generic-lts-trusty (--configure):
>   dependency problems - leaving unconfigured Errors were encountered
>   while processing:  linux-image-3.13.0-67-generic 
>   linux-image-extra-3.13.0-67-generic  linux-image-generic 
>   linux-generic  linux-generic-lts-trusty E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg
>   returned an error code (1)

So I tried installing linux-generic with `apt-get install linux-generic`, but that results in the same error message. I tried searching for the error message `Package linux-generic is not configured yet`, and tried some suggestions but nothing works.

I checked out my linux images:

```
$ dpkg -l | grep linux-image
iF  linux-image-3.13.0-67-generic        3.13.0-67.110           amd64        Linux kernel image for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-extra-3.13.0-67-generic  3.13.0-67.110           amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 3.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
iU  linux-image-generic                  3.13.0.67.73            amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
```

So I do seem to have linux-image-generic. I wouldn't know what could be wrong with it though.

Does anybody know what I can do to upgrade my kernel to >= 3.10? All tips are welcome!

Comment: apt-get upgrade linux-image*

Comment: Have you seen this Ubuntu Wiki page? https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds